# How do Time lords/Gallifreyans breed, and can they do so with humans?

Tags: doctor-who

How do Gallifreyans breed? Are they asexual - like Donna asked, 'Do you lop a limb off and sprout another one?'

And can humans and Gallifreyans inter-breed? Eight claimed he was half human on his mothers side, but that doesn't come up in any other incarnation.

Comment: For the most part, other than that the Time lords have advanced technology and two hearts (and sometimes super strength) they are otherwise indistinguishable from baseline humans.  Galifreyans are more like advanced posthumans than outright aliens.  Sometimes it seems implied that they could breed with humans, other times not so much.  I think in the movie the Doctor was half-human or something, which implies some ability to join DNA.  It also seems implied that at one point in the new series, the Doctor was worried that Amy's baby might be his.

Comment: Posthumans? Time lords are an ancient species that have existed long before humans; in order to be postanything they at one point had to have been the same species or the next evolutionary chapter. Granted riversong compicates things but other than an elongated life and the ability to regenerate, which could be caused by exposure to the time radiation of tardis travel, she is human not time lord/Gallifreyan.

Comment: Sorry, I mean "Posthuman" generally, but as fas as I know Dr Who writers have never directly said that the Galifreyan's have modified their bodies.  And yes I know Riversong is human, but still there was a period where the doctor seemed worried the baby might be his, somehow.

Comment: Couldnt it be general concern, with the timelords gone his companions are his only familly

Comment: I don't think so, The Doctor says "Let the baby be his [Rory's]", and also briefly he acts like Rory deserves to be the father rather than himself.

Comment: How do Gallifreyans breed? *Very* well, thank you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First, I'm going to assume you mean Gallifreyans, because ["Time Lord" is not a race](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/45850/13941).

Second, keep in mind that [*Doctor Who* has no canon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/48536/13941); no one in a position of creative or legal authority has ever laid down what is and isn't canon, and the two producers for New Who have both said they don't think canon is possible. That being true, generally off-screen events (audio stories, books, comics, etc) have less ontological inertia than things which actually happen during an episode of the show.

### Gallifreyans can probably have children with humans.

...Although it's never happened on screen.

[The Doctor's granddaughter Susan married a human in the 22nd century](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/47448/13941), and [one account says that they were unable to have children](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Legacy_of_the_Daleks) while [another says they did](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/An_Earthly_Child). Neither happened on screen.

The Fourth Doctor's companion [Leela](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Arc_of_Infinity_(TV_story)) [married a Gallifreyan Time Lord](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Arc_of_Infinity_(TV_story)), and in non-screen materials [they had the first natural-born child on Gallifrey in millennia](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Lungbarrow).

### Gallifreyan reproduction is not addressed much on screen

And it's pretty inconsistent.

The best I can do is point you at [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/48536/13941) again. The TL;DR is that in non-screen materials Gallifreyan reproduction is largely aided by cloning-like technology, but that this seems to be contradicted by some on-screen evidence that they reproduce more like we do.

Comment: At very least cloning is possible, as with the Doctor's daughter.

Answer (score -1):

Looms , and it made children too ( wrongly some people think not ) based on information about books and audios in https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Loom :

> “According to one account, upon being Loomed into the House of Lungbarrow, the Doctor was physically in the form of a child. (PROSE: Human Nature) Some children of other Houses, while being mentally or emotionally older, apparently did physically resemble children (PROSE: Of the City of the Saved...) Some Time Tots, a term specifically used for mental and physical children, were loomed. (PROSE: Apocrypha Bipedium)

Also they stoped natural reproduced from long time ago due to the cursed dispite they found the cured later they were long traditional using the looms so they see natural reproduction as low category and primitive they did not do it ( 11 level planet ) probably outsiders did so

Comment: This seems to be same exact answer you just gave to another question. Granted I don't know much about DW, but I don't think it would answer two different questions.

Answer (score -2):

Let me reintroduce my answer by first off stating Doctor Who has no aurthorised canon.[1] But let me also say that the Whoniverse does have an accepted base history establised  ( fan canon if you will ) by the diffrent media ( television, novels, audio, comics )  it is in.[2] It is a  history that in some cases is heavily debated. The debates arise out of what one wants to "accept as canon". Where much of the debates arrise over is what certain Whovians want to believe. ( i.e. the two stories of Atlantis )  But it boils down to if it is in one of the affore mention venues it can be accepted as "loose canon" if one wants. After all it is make beleive.

The most accepted form of official history is the televised series and that is what most consider "canon" bacause many dont follow any other venue. This is why so much is tied into the t.v. show. Case and point Paul's Doctors audio adventure has been made official part of the televised series through "Night of The Doctor" .And almost so  were the Panini comics. In 2007, Doctor Who: The Flood, strip editor Clayton Hickman says that Russell T Davies had authorised the comic strip to depict the regeneration of the Eighth Doctor into the Ninth Doctor at the end of the 2004–2005 arc. But was rejected.[3]

With the following established let me move onto the question. One possible way is looming.Looming is an asexual process of artificial genetic reproduction.[4] But another is by test tube science. See the following link.

> [DOC] Treatment for DOCTOR WHO : The Key to Time treatmentexaple_2_drwho.doc Though the Time Lords propagate their race by artificial fertilization and test tube gestation, ... the Doctor is getting; after all, the Doctor couldn't have built it without him. ... When the fleet of capsules is used for nothing but sample and intelligence

Also from Paul on it is accepted he is half human,[5] as much as it is accepted that Time Lords are asxual. ( The Doctors Wife, The End Of Time )[6] A woman has actually played the Doctor in "Exile". But how Pauls Dr. is accepted is open to interpretation ( see the Beginners Guide to Doctor Who and BBC's websight ) Also one way it has been handled is sugesting Paul's Dr. adventures in three different forms (novels, audio, and comics) take place in three separate continuities. As in "Zagreus" and "The Gallifrey Chronicles ". But "Mary's Story" contradicteds this. At even one time it was wonderd when the series returned if Pauls Doctor would be treated like the other two movies with Cushing " Dr. Who and the Daleks" and "Daleks – Invasion Earth: 2150 A.D" but that was put to rest in "Human Nature "as this accepted the movie as a bridge between old and new.  And in "Night of the Doctor" went as far to include Paul's compainions from the audio as part of
 the T.V. history.

( NOTE AS I AM NOT A 10 REPUTATION I CAN NOT POST MY LINKS TO SUPPORT MY FINDINGS. PLEASE LOOK FOR THEM IN THE COMMENT SECTION SND WHEN, IF, I REACH 10I WILL POST IN ANSWER. )

> [5]tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Howling:Is_the_Doctor_half-human%3F

Again though with a fantasy story like Who that has nothing set in stone it really boils down on what the individuals imagination wishes to accept. one is right and no one is wrong. This fall all this could change depending on the series and it is already rumored that Capaldi is a one season Who and the next is a woman.

> http://www.mirror.co.uk/tv/tv-news/doctor-who-could-peter-capaldis-3175645

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.  Also, I believe you're referring the the Meta-Crisis Doctor who is essentially a clone of the prime Doctor but with half human DNA.  The main Doctor (i.e. not the one that went with Rose Tyler to the alternate universe) is 100% Gallifreyan/Time Lord.

Comment: @Monty129, I disagree he asked how they reproduce and I answerd. And no Im not reffering to the meta-crisis hybrid (not clone) .And if you watch the movie w/ Paul you will see what we are talking about.He is not 100%.

Comment: You haven't cited any references to where it's stated Gallifreyan's reproduce through "test tube science", and the Doctor Who tv movie with Paul McGann stating he has half human on his mother's side has been ignored outright by all subsequent series.

Comment: @monty129, first you are absolutely incorrect about the movie,  it is accepted fully as canon and has not ignored.  As far as sighting things you havent sighted where his half human side has been ignored. I will find the episode for you, and if you will kindly back up your facts.

Comment: @Monty129, here is reference for the movie fact of him being half human and being canon...Im sorry it wont allow me to cut and paste quote so you will just have to read the whole article. http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Howling:Is_the_Doctor_half-human%3F

Comment: I wont even go into the "looming" process because that I believe is not part of the t.v. canon.

Comment: You haven't cited in your **answer** where your information comes from.  Stack Exchange requires answers to be backed up by facts.

Comment: @Monty129 neither did you but I have cited part so far that shows you are wrong. And I will prove the rest.

Comment: @rob -http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18314/the-doctor-is-half-human

Comment: The accepted answer for that question is that no, he's not half human, you've still not cited your references in your answer on this question, and you've yet to back up any of your answer with confirmed facts by either on screen proof or information confirmed by the producers of the tv show.

Comment: @Monty129, no thats not the accepted answer as I have already listed one reference to refute you and you have listed none to refute me. I can list more on the human side if you wish. I am currently looking through 50 years of vidio,books and audio to find the other for you. Im about ready to just delete my answer other than belabor my evidence I have given. No matter how many times "you" say Im wrong doesnt make it so.This is suppose to be fun.

Comment: @Monty129, [DOC] Treatment for DOCTOR WHO : The Key to Time treatmentexaple_2_drwho.doc Though the Time Lords propagate their race by artificial fertilization and test tube gestation, ... the Doctor is getting; after all, the Doctor couldn't have built it without him. ... When the fleet of capsules is used for nothing but sample and intelligence ... 

Still looking for actual episode though...

Comment: @Monty129, BESW in previous answer never sighted facts only referenced other Stack Exchange posts for that answer. Why not get on that? But now that both my comments are sighted from outside references I have met "the requirements ".

Comment: The **answer** needs to be properly cited, not the comments.  Perhaps you should have read the FAQ thoroughly before posting an answer.  The fact that it has (currently) 4 downvotes and no upvotes should indicate the quality of your answer.  While this is an entertaining site, it's also mainly for people seeking answers either from credible sources, or through extrapolation of data from said credible sources, of which you've provided neither.

Comment: @Monty129, yawn...I concur that I did not, at first, format my answer properly (curse us rookies) but I edited my answer now properly and just because you dont the sources does not make me wrong. One sight I believe is older than this one. And is a cornerstone on Whovian history. Also just because I have a -4 does not mean I am wrong either. Nor does saying so make you right. While I have only watched who for 40 yrs I will admit I dont know it all. But what I do comment on here and on other sights (some of which I am a moderator on because of my knowledge) are things I do know.

Comment: Like the meta-doctor is a hybrid not a clone. Im am on another SE page for only 4 days am only answerd like 3 questions and am already over 70 so I am learning how to "play this fourm". I HAVE given credible verifiable information and listed CREDIBLE accepted long term sources. Seems to me you just dont like to be wrong. Now will you please get a life...besides mine...and let this vendetta go.

Comment: @Monty129, P.S. in my previous comment i see now what you were referring to" But now that both my comments are sighted from outside references I have met "the requirements" " it should of read "both my comments in my answer " because at that time I had edited my answer to the proper format. Im sorry if you missed the edited statement and misunderstood my post. I didnt mean to confuse you I just thought it was obvious what was meant. Hopefully that clears a little up as the "answer" became properly cited yesterday. Sorry you missed that fact.

Comment: >[1] www.bbc.co.uk/doctorwho 
        Davies, Russel T. (2005). Doctor Who Magazine (356) 
        http://thewertzone.blogspot.com/2013/09/doctor-who-at-50-new-adventures.html 

>[2] http://www.whoniverse.net/ 
        http://www.thewhoniverse.com/ 
        http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Canon 
        http://www.bbcamerica.com/doctor-who/extras/dw50/fun-doctor-personality-quizzes/who-or-what-in-the-whoniverse-would-you-be/ 

>[3] Doctor Who: The Flood - The Complete Eighth Doctor Comic Strips Volume 4. London: Panini Books. 2007. pp. 216–223. ISBN 978-1-905239-65-8.

Comment: >[4] http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Pregnancy 

> [5]tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Howling:Is_the_Doctor_half-human%3F

 > [6]http://drwho.answers.wikia.com/wiki/We_now_know_that_Time_Lords_can_change_gender_during_regeneration._Can_they_change_species_(eg_Eocene,_Sontaran,_Cat)