# How do Time Lords reproduce?

Tags: doctor-who, time-lord

By looking at the sheer number of residents on Gallifrey (as shown in ***The Day of the Doctor***), we see both men women and several children.

How do(/did) the Time Lords reproduce? Is there any explanation about it?

Comment: When a Time Lord loves a Time Lady very much…

Comment: I think this is addressed here [How do Time lords/Gallifreyans breed, and can they do so with humans?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/50436/how-do-time-lords-gallifreyans-breed-and-can-they-do-so-with-humans)

Comment: @elrond thanks. that was what I was looking for

Comment: *Very* well, thank you.